# Java Selenium - Fetching data from HandsonTable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fetch data from Handsontable. The table contains 700 data, however when i am locating through the Xpath, At first only 27 data found out of 55 and when i scroll down it changes to 22 out of 40. every time its taking random data. Below I have tried to create a scroll and getColumnData functions.

```
private void scrollDown() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver();
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", rows().get(rows().size()-1));
}


protected LinkedList<WebElement> getColumnWebElement(String columnName)
   {
       LinkedList<WebElement> columnElement = new LinkedList<WebElement>();
       int indexColumn = getLocationOfColumnInHeader(columnName) + 3;
       WebElement headerRow = this.headerRow();
       List<WebElement> rows = this.rows();
       System.out.println(this.rows());
       for (WebElement currentRow : rows)
           if (currentRow != headerRow)
           {
               scrollDown();
               WebElement td = driver.getValidatedElementNoWait(currentRow, By.xpath("./td[" + indexColumn + "]"));
               if (td != null)
               {
                   columnElement.add(td);
               }
           }
       return columnElement;
   }
```

Is there anyway to read all dynamic changing data based on Column name.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: data is being dynamically pulled up with java script . you have to simulate the scroll down first till you load all the data then you may proceed with the scrape

Comment: @Uicorn I can add an answer with a function I use to scroll till the end but it's in python . if you want I can post it for you .

Comment: @ahmed.soli - in my case if i scroll till end it will display/load last 25 data rest will be hidden or based on scroll.

Comment: i think it doesn't matter if it's hidden as long as it is still available in the dom, but if it got deleted as the hide mechanism then there is no helping it

Comment: thats the point

Answer (score 0):

I used below workaround.

```
  public void changeTableAttribute() {
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver();
      WebElement element = driver().findElement(By.xpath("//hot-table/div[@class='handsontable-container handsontable htColumnHeaders']"));
      js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'height:15000px')", element);
  }
```